# Display attachment field depending on another boolean field

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables, one contains a boolean value and the other one contains an attachment field.

There is a 1-to-Many relationship between the 2 tables :

```
T1 (long ID_staff, txt firstname, attach signature)
T2 (long ID_signature, long fk_ID_staff, boolean isValid)
```

In my form, I display the INNER JOIN of those 2 tables. As result, I have fields :

```
long ID_signature, txt firstname, attach signature, boolean isValid
```

What I would like to do is display my attachment ("signature" field) in my form ONLY if isValid equals TRUE.

Is there an easy way to do that in VBA or directly in Access ?

Thanks

Comment: But you know SQL and what a `WHERE`-Clause is?

Comment: Then I would have to do 2 different queries, no ? I want all the rows, even when isValid = False, I just dont wanna display the attachment when that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for the [`IIf`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function.

```
SELECT ID_signature, firstname, IIf([isValid], [signature], NULL) AS ValidSignature
FROM <your join>
```

Comment: It indeed works, but I still have an issue. Even though I put ValidSignature as Source of my attachment control, the picture is not displaying. But the field is not empty. `IIf(T_SIGNATURE.signature_validee,T_PERSONNEL.visa.FileData,Null) AS ValidSignature
FROM T_PERSONNEL INNER JOIN...;`

Comment: I have never worked with attachment fields, so can't really help here. I suggest a new question, including the information whether it works when you directly use the table as source instead of the query. @LostReality

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIF function, for example

```
select ID_signature, [txt firstname], Iif([isValid] = "True",[attach signature], null) as [Signature] .....
```

Also, it is unwise to use spaces in column name, it is better to use `_` instead of space.